# How to get a reference to the minimum element in a multidimensional array?

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

For example there is an array:

```
$data = array(
    5,
    array(
        2, 
        8, 
        array(
            1, 
            4,
        ),
        3
    ),
);
```

How can I find the minimum element and keep a link to it? As example, when such an operation: `$data['min'] = &$data[1][2][0];`

That is, the result would be:

```
array {
  [0]=> int(5)
  [1]=> array {
    [0]=> int(2)
    [1]=> int(8)
    [2]=> array {
      [0]=> &int(1)
      [1]=> int(4)
    }
    [3]=> int(3)
  }
  ["min"]=> &int(1)
}
```

Tried through array_walk_recursive, but nothing happened:

```
$min = false;
$minLink = false;
array_walk_recursive($data, function(&$item, $key) use (&$min, &$minLink) {
    if ($item < $min OR !$min) {
        $minLink = &$item;
        $min = $item;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

My solution assumes that all leaf elements are compareable via `<`. I also assume that the `min`-reference is to be stored in the source array.

```
array_walk_recursive($data, function (&$item) use (&$data)
{
    if (!isset($data['min']) || $item < $data['min'])
    {
        $data['min'] = &$item;
    }
});
```

Comment: So it seems you're suggesting that it was the condition that was wrong, not the behaviour of the reference?

Comment: @TomFenech: The condition looks OK, but it seems to be impossible to correctly set `$minLink`. At the beginning of each call `$minLink` has the value `false`. After setting it it actually contains the reference (you can modify `$data`'s values through `$minLink`) but this information is lost between two subsequent calls. I have no explaination for this behaviour, it might be related to scoping issues? However strange, my version works correctly but as I see now it's merely by accident...